# Convert date to string format

Tags: vb.net, converters

I have successfully imported data from xls into dataGridView.
The date column in dataGridView is showing the DateTime format. I want this date column to be displayed in "dd MMM yyyy" format. I have tried as shown below:

```
connExcel.Open()
    Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    Dim SheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
    connExcel.Close()

    'Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open()
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" & SheetName & "]"
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel
    oda.Fill(dt)
    connExcel.Close()

    dt.Columns(1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")

    'Bind Data to GridView
    InvestorGridView.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
    InvestorGridView.DataSource = dt
    InvestorGridView.DataBind()
```

but it is giving me an error :

> Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ToString' accepts this number of arguments.   D:\TMV\TMV\Project\Investor\Investor\Investor.aspx.vb   68  9   Investor

Thanks

Comment: You get the error because you are not invoking ToString on a Date but on a DataColumn object that has not the overload you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because you are using `ToString` on a `DataColumn` which has no such overload like `DateTime`. That doesn't work anyway. The only way with the `DataTable` was if you'd add another string-column with the appropriate format in each row.

You should instead use the `DataGridViewColumn`'s [`DefaultCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
InvestorGridView.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd MMM yyyy"
```

**Update** if it's webforms and it's a `BoundField` you can use the [`DataFormatString`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateColumn" 
                HeaderText="DateColumn-Name" 
                SortExpression="DateColumn" 
                DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" />
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your help. But it said 'DefaultCellStyle' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. I have AutoGeneratedColumns = true here. whether it affects?

Comment: @Margaretha: You should have mentioned that it's webforms and not winforms ;)